# Office JS issue with recognising ListItems

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I'm trying to add a paragraph at the end of the document and escape the possibility of the newly added paragraph to be added inside a list (if the document is ending with a list).

I have the following code:

```
let paragraph = paragraphs.items[paragraphs.items.length - 1]
let p = paragraph.insertParagraph('', window.Word.InsertLocation.after)

if (paragraph.listItemOrNullObject) {
    p.detachFromList()
    p.leftIndent = 0
}
```

The following happens: if there is a ListItem, the code works. If not, it breaks inside the if condition, like I wrote `paragraph.listItem`.

Shouldn't this be used like this?

EDIT - error thrown:

```
name:"OfficeExtension.Error"
code:"GeneralException"
message:"GeneralException"
traceMessages:[] 0 items
innerError:null
▶debugInfo:{} 4 keys
    code:"GeneralException"
    message:"GeneralException"
    toString:function (){return JSON.stringify(this)}
    errorLocation:"Paragraph.detachFromList"
```

Comment: Please provide the error message you're receiving. It will help folks zero in on the issue much quicker.

Comment: You're right, updating the ticket now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listItemOrNullObject` will return a null object if it isn't a `ListItem`. Conceptually you're `if` is asking "if this is a list item or it isn't a list item" which effectively will also return true.

It is failing here you are attempting to detach from a non-existent list. I would take a look at `isListItem`. This will tell you specifically if the paragraph is a `ListItem` so you only execute `p.detachFromList()` when in fact it is part of a list.

Comment: Tried replacing it, got: `The property 'isListItem' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.`, but I am doing all this wrapped in: `return context.sync().then(() => { ... }`

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were already calling after syncing. You need to execute a sync() prior to reading properties as none of them are populated until you specifically request them to be. Take a look at https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/loadoption for information on how data gets populated locally.

Comment: Yes, that did it, I just added it to the `context.load(paragraph, " ... ")` call that was already there. Thanks!

Comment: check out my answer i think the issue is you are not checking if its null properly, check my sample. and sorry this is an issue with how we need to handle null. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

the issue here is that the *.isNullObject methods/properties does not return a regular js 'null' object, but a NullObject (a special framework type of null).

check out this code i rewrote it i think in a more efficient way. excuse my js, you can port it to ts.

hope this helps.

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
        var  listI = context.document.body.paragraphs.getLast().listItemOrNullObject;
        context.load(listI);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (listI.isNullObject) { // check out how i am validating if its null.
                    console.log("there is no list at the end")
                }
                else {
                    context.document.body.paragraphs.getLast().detachFromList();
                    context.document.body.paragraphs.getLast().leftIndent = 0;
                    return context.sync();
                }

            })
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see how it's used.